# How to find and replace two strings around two variables?

Tags: regex, replace, find

I'm new to regex and I came across a problem.

I have the following text: `| latitude = anynumber1  | longitude = anynumber2  |`

I want to know how I can use regex to find: `| latitude = anynumber1 | longitude = anynumber2 |`
and replace it with: `| coordinates = {{coord|anynumber1|anynumber2}} |`

I have many pages of the following format: `| latitude = anynumber1  | longitude = anynumber2  |`

just the numbers of latitude and longitude changes with every page, now I have to change it into a newer format on all the pages. How can I do it using regex find and replace?

Comment: Have you already tried anything? You know, `|` are special regex metacharacters and need escaping if you plan to match them as literal chars. What tool are you using?

Comment: No, I haven't tried anything. I'm totally new to this. And I don't know where to start. Yes, pipe `|` needs to be counted as a string here.

Comment: Anyway, what tool/programming language do you plan to use?

Comment: It is a third party application which supports regex find and replace. The application is written in C#.

Comment: Try *Find what*: `\|\s*latitude\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*\|\s*longitude\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*\|` and 
*Replace with*: `| coordinates = {{coord|$1|$2}} |`

Comment: No luck, it could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex-based replacement:

*Find what*: `\|\s*latitude\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*\|\s*longitude\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*\|` 
*Replace with*: `| coordinates = {{coord|$1|$2}} |`

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%7C%5Cs*latitude%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*(%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*%5C%7C%5Cs*longitude%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*(%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*%5C%7C&i=%7C%20latitude%20%3D%201%20%20%7C%20longitude%20%3D%202%20%20%7C%0D%0A%7C%20latitude%20%3D%20321%20%20%7C%20longitude%20%3D%2022%20%20%7C%0D%0A%7C%20latitude%20%3D%2031%20%20%7C%20longitude%20%3D%2042%20%20%7C&r=%7C%20coordinates%20%3D%20%7B%7Bcoord%7C%241%7C%242%7D%7D%20%7C)

*Details*:

- `\|` - a literal `|`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `latitude` - a string `latitude`
- `\s*=\s*`  - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`)
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more digits
- `\s*\|\s*` -  a `|`  enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `longitude` - a `longitude` text
- `\s*=\s*` -  a `|`  enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 2 capturing 1 or more digits
- `\s*\|` - 0+ whitespaces + `|`

The `$1` and `$2` in the replacement pattern insert the values captured into Group 1 and 2 respectively.

[image]

Comment: Great it is working. Thanks! What happens if                                               | latitude = anynumber1 | longitude = anynumber2 | are two different lines?

Comment: It does not matter as `\s` matches both horizontal and vertical whitespace symbols. The `*` quantifier makes it match 0 or more occurrences. Check [Regular-Expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) site for more details on regular expressions.

Comment: It is not working when I have changed lines. See [http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%7c%5cs*latitude%5cs*%3d%5cs*(%5cd%2b)%5cs*%5c%7c%5cs*longitude%5cs*%3d%5cs*(%5cd%2b)%5cs*%5c%7c&i=%7c+latitude+%3d+1++%0d%0a%7c+longitude+%3d+2++%0d%0a%7c+latitude+%3d+321++%0d%0a%7c+longitude+%3d+22++%0d%0a%7c+latitude+%3d+31++%0d%0a%7c+longitude+%3d+42&r=%7c+coordinates+%3d+%7b%7bcoord%7c%241%7c%242%7d%7d+%7c] (here)

Comment: Try replacing `\s*` with `\W*`.

Comment: Dear Wiktor, how do the code work for a negative decimal number?

Comment: Add `-?` before `\d`